# How to add a whole sentence to a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to add a whole sentence inside a list in python but when I give :

```
name = "My name is steven"
name = list(name)
print(name)
```

The output is:

```
['M', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 's', 't', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'n']
```

but I want it in the form of :

```
["My name is steven"]
```

further I have to add other sentences also inside list. What can I do?

Comment: `name =[name]` .

Comment: As you wrote yourself: `["My name is steven"]`, then replace the string with the variable name.

Comment: with this you're importing each character's index into an index of the list, just use [name] instead of list(name)

Comment: If `names` is a list you can add more values with `names.append('another value')`. Might I suggest that you read the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/index.html)? It will answer all those basic questions.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing iterable to list so it will convert string to list of characters in string

```
name = "My name is steven"
name = [name]  # This way you can convert it into desired output
print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using .append especially if you have additonal sentences to add.

```
a=[]
name="My name is Steven"
a.append(name)
# a=["My name is Steven"]
```